# Datagrid SelectedIndex When Line not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a problem with my Datagrid. (MVVM)
I have a textbox that sets the SelectedIndex depending on where I click in the text. This works!
But the table in the datagrid can get quite long, and if the line that I want to highlight is not visible when clicking in the textbox it does not mark the line as selected.

So my question is if it is possible to select the line even though it is not visible? So if i scroll down that it shows the line as selected.
Or what would probably be better just jump to this line if not visible. (Set to top row or scroll to it automatically). Is this possible, if yes how?

Here is the xaml of the datagrid :

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgDecodedMsg"
                CanUserSortColumns="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                IsTabStop="False"
                ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding DecodeSelectedGridIdx, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MsgTypGridLineListVar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                Margin="10,111,10,0">
```

This is how I highlight the Rows : (The rows don't get highlighted even if I set index on DecodeSelectedGridIdx and call the OnPropertychanged)

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                  </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
```

This is how I set the index :

```
public int DecodeSelectedGridIdx
{
  set
  {
    this.m_decodeSelectedGridIdx = value;
...
    OnPropertyChanged("DecodeSelectedGridIdx");
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the `DataGrid` in the view and call the `ScrollIntoView` method:

```
private void dtgDecodedMsg_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dtgDecodedMsg.ScrollIntoView(dtgDecodedMsg.SelectedItem);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgDecodedMsg" ... SelectionChanged="dtgDecodedMsg_SelectionChanged">
...
```

You could wrap this functionality in a behaviour if you intend to use it in several views: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I have the following problem with this: If i change the index from klicking in the textbox this error happens :           Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
-> If i show the selectedIndex with a messagebox it shows -1

Comment: I did some more testing about this. If let's say line 0 - 23 is visible and i klick in the textbox to select line 24 the SelectedGridIdx will be set (debugged this) and the OnPropertyChanged is called. But i do not hit the breakpoint at dtgDecodedMsg_SelectionChanged. So it seems it completely ignores the new index if it is out of "sight" ?

Comment: Hello,i managed to get it working. I used the SelectedItem instead of selectedIndex. Now the ScrollIntoView also works.Thank you !